# Curl command through python

Tags: python, rest, curl

I am attempting to programmatically run a curl command. I have `os` imported, but I can not seem to get effective results with the following code. (Dummy hackathon API data)

```
os.system('curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"merchant_id\": \"57cf75cea73e494d8675ec49\",\"medium\": \"balance\",\"purchase_date\": \"2017-01-22\",\"amount\": 1,\"description\": \"string\"}" "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/accounts/5883e3351756fc834d8ebe89/purchases?key=b84d3a153e2842b8465bcc4fde3d1839"')
```

For some odd reason, the above code does not effectively just run a system command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 01:**

You can use the **`subprocess`** module to execute a shell command from Python.

Example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = '''curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"merchant_id\": \"57cf75cea73e494d8675ec49\",\"medium\": \"balance\",\"purchase_date\": \"2017-01-22\",\"amount\": 1,\"description\": \"string\"}" "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/accounts/5883e3351756fc834d8ebe89/purchases?key=b84d3a153e2842b8465bcc4fde3d1839"'''
>>> args = cmd.split()
>>> subprocess.call(args)
```

If you can using Python version 3.5(or later), you can use the `subprocess.run` command instead.

**METHOD 02:**

Use **`requests`** if you:
 - Want to write a Pythonic code for the POST request.
 - Prefer clean and extensible code!

```
>>> import requests
>>> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
>>> data = {"merchant_id\": "57cf75cea73e494d8675ec49\","medium\": "balance\", "purchase_date\": "2017-01-22\","amount\": 1, "description\": "string\"}
>>> url = "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/accounts/5883e3351756fc834d8ebe89/purchases?key=b84d3a153e2842b8465bcc4fde3d1839"
>>> response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Neither one is quite working for me. DO they both need to be run in python 2? Is there a way I can look at the json output

Comment: @Nick The methods work for both major Python versions.

Comment: @Nick For the 2nd method, you can get the response as JSON by calling `response.json()`

Comment: @Nick I think you can use `print` function for this. I would also like to suggest you go through the documentation of the respective libraries.